# What is the right way to debug React Native Expo project on WebStorm?

Tags: react-native, expo, webstorm

My run cinfigurations:[image]
Before-Launch:
[image: Before-Launch Configuration]
package.json:
[image]
When i run `Expo` configuration:
[image]

Is that any problem?

When i debug or run this 'Expo' configuration, the `npm start` script is not running, and i can't set breakpoints in WebStorm to debug my Code.
After i stopped project, it shows `Error running 'Expo', Unknown error`

Comment: Must be related to recent Expo updates. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50168. Fix (plus updated docs) will be available in 2021.1.1

Comment: As for now, my workaround is that change bundler port between 19000 and 19001. -- If 19000 not working, I'd like to change to 19001. But this seems not a good choice